# Error with aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server

when i execute the below query i get the error "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery." How can i write the same query without getting the error.

```
SELECT CCMID[Client],CCMName[Company],
    (SELECT SUM( (Select SUM( PAm) from PaySalReg(NOLOCK) 
    Join PayEleMas (NOLOCK) ON  PSPCo =PEPCo
    where PSRAMId=AMId and PEMDedTy ='SSC' 
    and PProYe=(SELECT DOYe FROM DefOMonth)
    and PProMo=(SELECT DOMo-1 FROM DefOMonth))
    -
    (Select SUM(PAm) from PaySalReg(NOLOCK) 
    Join PayEleMas (NOLOCK) ON  PSPCo =PEPCo
    where PSRAMId=AMId and PEMDedTy ='PRTY'
    and PProYe=(SELECT DOYe FROM DefOMonth)
    and PProMo=(SELECT DOMo-1 FROM DefOMonth)))
    from AssMas(NOLOCK) WHERE ACID = CCMID ) AS [Net Pay],
    COUNT(PAMId)[No. of Associates] 
    FROM PaySalReg
    JOIN AssMas ON AMId =PSRAMId
    JOIN CorpClMas ON ACID = CCMID
    WHERE PProMon='10'
    AND PProYe='2014'
    AND PAPPSTA IS NULL
    GROUP BY CCM_Name,CCM_ID
```

Comment: Where do you get that error? In the first `SUM`? Is the error because of `PProYe=(SELECT DOYe FROM DefOMonth)`? Is `DefOMonth` a 1-row table? If you provide your table structure you may get a better solution to your problem.

Comment: @Andrew the error is not because PProYe=(SELECT DOYe FROM DefOMonth),yes it is a one roe table. The error is in the first SUM()

Comment: I think that query has too many nested subqueries and it's very hard to read and understand; there must be an easier way to get the desired result. Can you post the table structure and what info you need?

Comment: This appears to be a financial application. Is there a reason you are littering your queries with NOLOCK? Are you ok with missing and/or duplicate rows? Here is one of many articles about how bad that hint is. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2009/04/10/how-dirty-are-your-reads.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the outer aggregate, and wrap the query in a sub query...
Then perform the aggregate on the sub query...
Something like this...

```
SELECT CCMID, CCMName, [No. of Associates], SUM([Net Pay])
FROM (
    SELECT Client as CCMID, Company as CCMName,
        (Select SUM( PAm) from PaySalReg(NOLOCK) 
        Join PayEleMas (NOLOCK) ON  PSPCo =PEPCo
        where PSRAMId=AMId and PEMDedTy ='SSC' 
        and PProYe=(SELECT DOYe FROM DefOMonth)
        and PProMo=(SELECT DOMo-1 FROM DefOMonth))
        -
        (Select SUM(PAm) 
        from PaySalReg(NOLOCK) 
        Join PayEleMas (NOLOCK) ON  PSPCo =PEPCo
        where PSRAMId=AMId and PEMDedTy ='PRTY'
        and PProYe=(SELECT DOYe FROM DefOMonth)
        and PProMo=(SELECT DOMo-1 FROM DefOMonth)) AS [Net Pay],

        COUNT(PAMId) AS [No. of Associates] 
    FROM PaySalReg
        JOIN AssMas ON AMId =PSRAMId
        JOIN CorpClMas ON ACID = CCMID
    WHERE PProMon='10'
    AND PProYe='2014'
    AND PAPPSTA IS NULL) data
GROUP BY CCMID, CCMName, [No. of Associates]
```

(untested, as you didn't supply a data structure.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the aggregate queries to a new function(Scalar function) and call the function from your procedure .(replace the aggregate query by the function)

Comment: Scalar functions are horrible for performance. You should do your best to avoid scalar functions whenever possible.

Comment: Yes , I know that, I forgot to mention this..thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your coding-style and indentation a bit and the problem becomes visible:

```
SELECT
    CCMID[Client],
    CCMName[Company],
    (
        SELECT SUM(
            (   
                Select SUM(PAm) from PaySalReg(NOLOCK) 
                Join PayEleMas (NOLOCK) ON  PSPCo =PEPCo
                where PSRAMId = AMId
                    and PEMDedTy = 'SSC' 
                    and PProYe = (SELECT DOYe FROM DefOMonth)
                    and PProMo = (SELECT DOMo-1 FROM DefOMonth)
            ) - (
                Select SUM(PAm) from PaySalReg(NOLOCK) 
                Join PayEleMas (NOLOCK) ON  PSPCo =PEPCo
                where PSRAMId = AMId
                    and PEMDedTy = 'PRTY'
                    and PProYe = (SELECT DOYe FROM DefOMonth)
                    and PProMo = (SELECT DOMo-1 FROM DefOMonth)
            )
        )
        from AssMas(NOLOCK)
        WHERE ACID = CCMID
    ) AS [Net Pay],

    COUNT(PAMId) [No. of Associates] 

FROM PaySalReg
JOIN AssMas    ON AMId = PSRAMId
JOIN CorpClMas ON ACID = CCMID
WHERE  PProMon = '10'
    AND PProYe = '2014'
    AND PAPPSTA IS NULL
GROUP BY CCM_Name, CCM_ID
```

The `SUM()` in line 4 is the problem. And I don't see why you would put `SUM()` there at all, the 2 subqueries you're substracting will only ever give 1 result each since there's no `GROUP BY`. So `value - value` doesn't need a `SUM()` around it:

```
SELECT
    CCMID[Client],
    CCMName[Company],
    (
        SELECT (    
                Select SUM(PAm) from PaySalReg(NOLOCK) 
                Join PayEleMas (NOLOCK) ON  PSPCo =PEPCo
                where PSRAMId = AMId
                    and PEMDedTy = 'SSC' 
                    and PProYe = (SELECT DOYe FROM DefOMonth)
                    and PProMo = (SELECT DOMo-1 FROM DefOMonth)
            ) - (
                Select SUM(PAm) from PaySalReg(NOLOCK) 
                Join PayEleMas (NOLOCK) ON  PSPCo =PEPCo
                where PSRAMId = AMId
                    and PEMDedTy = 'PRTY'
                    and PProYe = (SELECT DOYe FROM DefOMonth)
                    and PProMo = (SELECT DOMo-1 FROM DefOMonth)
            )
        from AssMas(NOLOCK)
        WHERE ACID = CCMID
    ) AS [Net Pay],

    COUNT(PAMId) [No. of Associates] 

FROM PaySalReg
JOIN AssMas    ON AMId = PSRAMId
JOIN CorpClMas ON ACID = CCMID
WHERE  PProMon = '10'
    AND PProYe = '2014'
    AND PAPPSTA IS NULL
GROUP BY CCM_Name, CCM_ID
```

**Sidenote:** This query definitely looks like it could be refactored, but that was not your question :)